# Python 3 - Check letters in string with the next letter

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, indexing

If I have a string

```
String = 'ABCEEFGH'
```

How can I check what letter is beside each letter without going out of index?

```
for index in range(len(String)):
    if String[index] == String[index+1]: 
        print('Double')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), [slicing](http://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/) the string up to the second last character:

```
String = 'ABCEEFGH'

for ind,ch in enumerate(String[:-1]):
    if ch == String[ind+1]:
        print('Double')
```

In your own code the logic would be the same `len(String)-1` but enumerate is the way to go:

```
for index in range(len(String)-1):
    if String[index] == String[index+1]:
        print('Double')
```

The fact you seen to only want to check if  any two adjacent characters are identical, maybe using [any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) would be best:

```
String = 'ABCEEFGH'

if any( ch == String[ind+1] for ind, ch in enumerate(String[:-1])):
        print('Double',ch)
```

`any` will short circuit and break the loop as soon the condition is `True`or else evaluate to `False` if we have no match.

Comment: Wow thank you. I did try using range(len(String)-1) earlier but I wasn't getting the first letter of the word

Comment: @Torched90, no worries, `[-1]` is indexing, getting the last character, `[:-1]` is slicing

Answer (score 1):

These kinds of problems are almost always easier if you think of comparing with the *previous* letter instead of the next one. It's a lot easier to remember letters you've already seen than to look ahead.

```
text = 'ABCEEFGH'
prev = ''
for letter in text:
    if letter == prev:
       print("letter duplicated:", letter)
    prev = letter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> text = 'ABCEEFGH'
>>> for c1, c2 in zip(text, text[1:]):
        if c1 == c2:
            print 'double'


double
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
for match in re.findall(r'([a-z])\1', your_string):
    print('Double letters found here.')
```